# What's the expression for "someone doing what you intended to do before you"

Tags: phrase-requests

I know this expression in my own language, and I think I've heard it a couple of times in English, but it completely slipped my mind. I can give an example to make it easier for you to understand what expression I'm looking

> I wanted to ask her out. But then she spoke. "You wanna grab dinner, or something". (expression)

Basically something saying; she got the before me. Or something like that. Sorry if this is too vague, but please try your best. If there's any Norwegians reading this question, here's the expression or phrase in Norwegian: "Å komme noen i forveien".

Alright, hope I gave you all enough to work with. I think it's a pretty common expression. Also, sorry for the really bad written example. I just need to make something quick, it simply there to paint a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**She beat me to it**

The phrase [**beat someone to it**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/beat-someone-to-it) is often used when someone else performs an action before one who intends to perform it.

A somewhat less positive alternative is [**jump the gun**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-the-gun) which means to do something before it is appropriate to do it. For your example, that may have been used in a somewhat old fashioned society which considers girls taking the lead in dating inappropriate!

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about. I had just forgotten the phrase. Thanks for the other one though, I didn't know about it, but now I do.

Comment: there is also a "took the wind from my sails" idiom where someone getting out ahead removes the force behind the other. ... and metaphorically can be used even for someone who spoke first at a meeting and proposed the points you meant to .

Comment: At risk of looking like a sour grape, may I suggest that in a formal context the examples I gave might be  appropriate: The opposition pre-empted our proposal by doing X and their defence anticipated our strategy in every detail.

Comment: @Aethelbald, I agree, in a formal setting. My answer to the title question would have been **"anticipatory"** but the example given in the question suggested a less formal tone.

Comment: @Pam, indeed...

Answer (score 0):

**in anticipation**  or **pre-emptively**.

Google translates "Å komme noen i forveien" as "Getting someone in advance" which looks roughly equivalent.